# Prove that subsequences of a sequence with infinite range contained in a compact set X converges to a point in X.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, proof-explanation

I have a question about a step regarding the following proof from Rudin theorem 3.6a),

Proof:

Let E be the range of the sequence ${p_n}$ since E is a infinite subset of a compact set it has a limit point in X, call this point p. We can choose a $n_1$ such that $d(p_{n_1},p) < 1 $ and this is true for infinitely many $p_{n_i}$. Choose $n_1,..,n_{i-1}$ such that $d(p_{n_k},p) < 1  \quad (1)$. Having chosen these $n_1,..,n_{i-1}$ we know that all neighborhoods of p contains infinitely many points of E, hence there are points $n_{i} > n_{i-1}$ such that $ d(p_{n_i},p) < (1/i) \quad (2)$ choosing these points we get a subsequence converging to the point p.

---

Normally I find all steps in a proof necessary, but at step (1) in the above proof I do not see why we have to choose these points $p_{n_1},..,p_{n_1}$ at all.

Is it not sufficient to directly choose all points points $p_{i}$ satisfying (2) for the subsequence?

Comment: It looks like a typo. You want $d(p_{n_1},p)<1$, $d(p_{n_2},p)<1/2$, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in (1) choose $n_1,n_2,...,n_{i-1}$ such that $d(p_{n_k},p) \lt \frac{1}{n_k}$ is what he mean. Your may read it wrongly in the book or it could be a typo (!!!). we are choosing $n_i$ inductively such that $d(p_{n_i},p) \lt \frac{1}{n_i}$, this is the property we want to show $p_{n{i}} \longrightarrow p$